# How to select rows from data set based on the date(form in mm-dd-yy) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

New to python...

I have a data set contains data from 2012-12-28 to 2013-03-29. But the form of date is in mm-dd-yy type, and I want to remove the row before year 2013. I have tried to convert form into yy-mm-dd but somehow it failed...

So are there anyway to remove rows based on the date? Thank you for answering!

I have create a sample data set as an simple example. I want to remove the first three rows in this sample data set.

```
date = ["12-28-12", "12-29-12", "12-30-12", "01-12-13", "02-25-13", "02-10-13", "03-28-13", "03-29-13"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Line1': np.arange(8), 
               "StartDate": date})
print(df)

 Line1 StartDate
0      0  12-28-12
1      1  12-29-12
2      2  12-30-12
3      3  01-12-13
4      4  02-25-13
5      5  02-10-13
6      6  03-28-13
7      7  03-29-13
```

Comment: What was the code you tried, and why did it fail (i.e., any possible error you got)?

Answer (score 3):

**`to_datetime`**

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.StartDate)
```

***Option 1***
**`loc`** with **`dt.year`**

```
df.loc[df.StartDate.dt.year >= 2013]
```

***Option 2***
**`drop`** with **`index`**

```
df.drop(df[df.StartDate.dt.year < 2013].index)
```

Both result in

```
   Line1     StartDate
3      3    2013-01-12
4      4    2013-02-25
5      5    2013-02-10
6      6    2013-03-28
7      7    2013-03-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime provides built-in functions for such conversion, and here is a short example.

```
import datetime
df['ActualDate']=df['StartDate'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, 
"%m-%d-%y").date())
df['ValidDate']=df['ActualDate'].apply(lambda x: x.year>2012)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since python use ISO 8601 for dates i'll recommend you to translate every date to a tuple in the format `[(year,month,day), (...)]` in that way you can store a lot of info with a low use of resources, you can do this with a tupe/List Comprehension

```
date_list=["12-28-12", "12-29-12", "12-30-12", "01-12-13", "02-25-13", "02-10-13", "03-28-13", "03-29-13"]

def iso_8601(dt):
    dt=list([x.split('-') for x in dt])
    dt=[int (x) for x in dt] #makes every part of the list an integer
    dt.reverse() #the list will start with the year
    dt.append(dt[1]) # add the day at the end
    dt.pop(1) # delete the element in position 1
    #add any extra control flow statements
    #option 1
    return dt # return the date in list form
    #option 2
    return tuple(dt) # will return a tuple instead
    #option 3 use only if you want to store strings instead integers
    return [str(x) for x in dt]
    #option 3.1 decrease memory usage
    return tuple([str(x) for x in dt])
    #option 4 add a control to swap between every option before


cache=[iso_8601(x) for x in lista if x[0]>=13]
```

if you only want a simple string per item then you have 2 options:
use the third option of iso_8601 and change cache to:

```
cache=["-".join(iso_8601(x)) for x in lista if (int(x[0])>=13)]
```

if you stored every element as a  integer list:

```
cache=[("-".join(*[str(y) for y in iso_8601(x)]) ) for x in lista if (x[0]>=13)]
```

The list Comprehension structure is defined by the next estructure
where:

```
LISTA :: is the original iterable list
RESULT :: any item to store with 1 or more variable
COMPARATIVE :: logic Clause
COMP_stm :: comprehension statement
L_OP :: any logic operation
ITERABLE_ELEMENT:: is the variable used to obtain ELEMENT from the original list
FUNC :: Any function that returns a value of any type
|| :: OR :: anything on the left or the right is valid or similar
ATTRIB :: any attribute that changes the value of the RESULT
... :: etc.
VALUE :: any value
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ COMP_stm ] :: python will store the element in memory as a real list
( COMP_stm ) :: python will store only a comprehension iterable object
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                          << sintaxis >> 
COMP_stm ::
    RESULT for ITERABLE_ELEMENT in LISTA  if (COMPARATIVE)

RESULT ::
    ITERABLE_ELEMENT || FUNC( ITERABLE_ELEMENT ) || x.ATTRIB() || ...
COMPARATIVE ::
    ITERABLE_ELEMENT L_OP VALUE
ITERABLE_ELEMENT ::
    any word that will point the iteraton element in the list, similar to
    "i" in the "for" cycle
```

> the comprehension object is a form that python knows how to manage all
>   the data, but it doesn't store any result, instead, it will execute
>   every iteration over petition, this form saves a lot of time and keeps
>   memory usage low, but it depends on the source of the data, this means
>   that if you deleted or changed the data before use the comprehension
>   object, this will raise a error.
>
> Also the comprehension object only works forward over the iterable
>   object, it does not allow any changes or select a specific element
>   inside because is never stored, the actual RESULT is assigned directly
>   to the iterable variable pointer (for example i when we use a for cycle)

also the escape character * before any 2d array will introduce every element of it to the function as an independent argument as example:

```
def function(arg1,arg2,arg3,):
    (...)
```

then:

```
function ([ VALUE_A, VALUE_B, VALUE_C, ... ])::
```

This will store the list in arg1 and will raise an Exception because arg2 and arg3 are empty

```
function (*[ VALUE_A, VALUE_B, VALUE_C, ... ])::
```

This form will store VALUE_A inside arg1, VALUE_B inside arg2 and so on

.

i'm open to comments over my code :D

Answer (score 0):

In general it's best practice to move dates into the index. This enables some nice tricks.

```
date = ["12-28-12", "12-29-12", "12-30-12", "01-12-13", "02-25-13", "02-10-13", "03-28-13", "03-29-13"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Line1': np.arange(8)}, 
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(date, name='StartDate'))
df = df.sort_index()
```

Now you can use the following:

```
df['2013':]
```